# Build dependencies troublesome in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, developer-tools

I have to use Eclipse every now and then, to compile a medium sized project with a dependency (Let A depending on B). Both have Debug and Release configurations.

The behavior that I want includes:

1. whenever a file of A is modified, a build should recompile it;
2. whenever a file of B is modified, a build should recompile it and force a link of A;
3. this should hold for the Debug or Release builds independently;
4. a launch of the executable should perform the necessary builds;
5. there must be a centralized way (just one place) to select the current configuration (Debug or Release).

Despite my efforts so far, I face numerous problems such as builds not being performed as should, or being performed on the wrong configuration or excution of an unexpected configuration... Quite often the only way to rescue is a Clean followed by a Build. A long story of frustrations, with countless lengthy but useless builds.

Two questions:

- do other people experience the same phenomenon ?
- is there a simple way to "guarantee" the behaviors 1 to 4 ?

Note that makefiles are not an option.

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to use an IDE as a CI/CD pipeline. consider using CI/CD tooling instead.

Comment: @FrankThomas: not at all, my question relates to the normal edit/compile/run cycle. Dependencies management works seamlessly in Visual Studio, and is a pain in the neck under Eclipse.